# Use Two styles in an elements.style properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hellow everyone,

I'm using the below code to Highlight the row of an table. I was wondering whether it is possible to add marquee effects ( i.e moving text from left to right ) i.e

```
<marquee>TEXT</marquee>
```

in same row. For example say now a current time is 12:45 Am then, it'd select class ra1 and have red bckground. At same time , I want to add marquee effects in same active row and when after 45 minutes, another row i.e class raa3 will be active and will have red background. I want to have now marquee effects in this row now i.e class ra3 which is currently selected and active.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName, today) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent =
    document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  if (typeof today == 'undefined') {
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  } else {
    tablinks[today].className += " active";
  }
}

let now = new Date().getHours() * 100 + new
Date().getMinutes();
let times = [45, 100, 145];
let classes = ['ra1', 'ra3', ];
let selected = classes[times.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => now >=
  curr ? idx : acc)];
if (selected){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(selected);
  for(var i=0;i<elements.length; i++)
      elements[i].style.background = 'red';
}
```

```css
.tabcontent { display: none }
```

```html
<div class="tab" style="margin-top: 1.6%;  ">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Sun0') ">Sun</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Mon0')">Mon</button>

</div>

<div id="Sun0" class="tabcontent" id="np">


  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table>
      <col width="65%">
      <col width="35%">
      <tr>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="ra1">10:15-11:00AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Sunday </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="ra3">11:00-11:45AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Sunday</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="Mon0" class="tabcontent">

  <!--Monnday-->
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table>
      <col width="65%">
      <col width="35%">
      <tr>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="ra1">10:15-11:00AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Monday</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="ra3">11:00-11:45AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Monday</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't completely understand what you are asking. You want a marquee in a table cell? Yes it is possible. But what is you script about?

Comment: My bad, I've now edited my question. Hope I have inlcluded all the details.

Comment: @SagarRawal did you see the answer? did it solve your problem?

Comment: yest I'm trying to create the effect but neither it highlights nor it take effects. I'm still stuck in this one from  couple of hours. here is the code can you have a bit look at it https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2j3ckof7nFGUkg5X3ZfN0MwdEE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get everything inside the selected div using `innerHTML` and then you can wrap it inside "" tags using `elements[i].innerHTML = "<marquee>" + elements[i].innerHTML + "</marquee>"`

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName, today) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent =
    document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  if (typeof today == 'undefined') {
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  } else {
    tablinks[today].className += " active";
  }
}

let now = new Date().getHours() * 100 + new
Date().getMinutes();
let times = [45, 100, 145];
let classes = ['ra1', 'ra3', ];
let selected = classes[times.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => now >=
  curr ? idx : acc)];
if (selected){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(selected);
  for(var i=0;i<elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].style.background = 'red';
      elements[i].innerHTML = "<marquee>" + elements[i].innerHTML + "</marquee>";
 }
}
```

```css
.tabcontent { display: none }
```

```html
<div class="tab" style="margin-top: 1.6%;  ">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Sun0') ">Sun</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Mon0')">Mon</button>

</div>

<div id="Sun0" class="tabcontent" id="np">


  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table>
      <col width="65%">
      <col width="35%">
      <tr>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="ra1">10:15-11:00AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Sunday </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="ra3">11:00-11:45AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Sunday</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="Mon0" class="tabcontent">

  <!--Monnday-->
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table>
      <col width="65%">
      <col width="35%">
      <tr>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="ra1">10:15-11:00AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Monday</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="ra3">11:00-11:45AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Monday</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```